# Multivariable integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

What is the result of the following integral?

$$ 2 \cdot \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{2s}}
\int_{1-s}^{\infty}\frac{b}{\sqrt{2 \pi u^3}}e^{-\frac{b^2}{2u}} du db$$

where $0 \leq s \leq 1 $ is a constant

Thank you..

Comment: Is $s$ a constant?

Comment: Yes s is a constant..

Comment: Please don't use the asterisk for multiplication. (I started editing them out, but @user17762 beat me to it.) The asterisk denotes *convolution* in mathematics.

Comment: Ok Prof. Olsen. I wont.

Comment: There is a problem: The inner integral is wrt $b$, but $b$ also appears outside the inner integral. Did you mean $du\,db$ at the end?

Comment: fixed. yes you are right.

Comment: If you change the order of the integrals, the $b$ integral can be evaluated immediately. Did you try that and see where it leads to?

Comment: i see.. i will try that way. thank you.

Comment: what about $s$. Is $s<1$?

Comment: Fixed the condition on s.

Comment: Interesting question... Looks like some integral that would appear in physics(looks a bit like the Fourier transform between position and momentum space in quantum mechanics...). I would definitely suggest you evaluate the b integral first. Then hopefully your expression will become simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why nobody is giving an answer?

The integral involving $b$ is:
$$
\int^\infty_0 be^{-(\frac{u+s}{2us}b^2)}db = \frac{su}{s+u}.
$$
The original integral becomes:
$$
2\int^\infty_{1-s}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi s}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi u^3}}\frac{su}{s+u} du = \frac{\sqrt{s}}{\pi} \int^\infty_{1-s}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}(s+u)} du
$$
Let $t = \sqrt{u}\in [\sqrt{1-s},\infty)$, and $du = 2tdt$, then the integral becomes:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{s}}{\pi} \int^\infty_{1-s}\frac{1}{\sqrt{u}(s+u)} du = \frac{2\sqrt{s}}{\pi}\int^{\infty}_{\sqrt{1-s}}\frac{1}{(s+t^2)} dt.
$$
Now make use of the following integral:
$$
\int \frac{1}{a^2+x^2}dx = \frac{1}{a}\arctan\frac{x}{a} +C
$$
and I think you can pick it from here.